# How can I pass a password to the "su" command?

Tags: unix, authentication, passwords

I have a program that is going to take a password as input and then do a shell execute to perform a "su" (switch user) command in UNIX.  However, I don't know how to pass the password variable to the UNIX su command.  The language I have to use for this is pretty limited (UniBasic).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, the best way to do that would be a setuid-root binary that ask for the password then execute whatever command is needed but it requires knowledge you say not to possess.  I'd advise in looking at [sudo(1)](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudo.html) instead.

Comment: I'm going to go w/ the setuid-root option.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could ssh to localhost as another user to execute whatever command you want. Or, use sudo and edit /etc/sudoers such that sudo does not ask for a password. However, there could be security implications.

EDIT: Please let me know why when you vote it down. My answer may not be perfect but at least it works. I do that myself for some licensed software that can only be run under a weird user name.

Comment: I don't know why this was voted down, seems like a perfectly good workaround.

Answer (score 3):

You do *not* want to specify the password as a command-line argument. Not so much because of  @unwind's answer (scripts could be made private) but because if someone runs a list of processes, you could see the command argument and hence the password in question.

Comment: +1 one because it boogles my mind how many times I see people asking about setting a password on the command line. So many people should have their UNIX/Linux operating licenses revoked...

Comment: So is there a reasonable solution?  Let's say I want to create a private script with 710 perms that does a very specific task as another username (in my case start up postgres as postgres).  what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The version of su I have on my Linux server does not support such an option. I checked sudo, but it doesn't either. They want to do the prompting themselves, to ensure it's done in a safe manner and (I guess) to discourage people from putting passwords verbatim in scripts and so on.

Comment: sudo can be configured such that no password is asked.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at the 'expect' utility that was designed to script complex user inputs into a programs that weren't flexible enough to receive this input from places other than stdin.